# Databricks spark-xml when reading tags ending in "/>" return values are null

Tags: apache-spark, xml-parsing, databricks

I'm using the latest version of spark-xml (0.4.1) with scala 11, when I read some xml that contains tags ending with "/>" the corresponding values ​​are null, fallow the example:

XML:

```
<Clients>
    <Client ID="1" name="teste1" age="10">
        <Operation ID="1" name="operation1">
        </Operation>
        <Operation ID="2" name="operation2">
        </Operation>
    </Client>
    <Client ID="2" name="teste2" age="20"/>
    <Client ID="3" name="teste3" age="30">
        <Operation ID="1" name="operation1">
        </Operation>
        <Operation ID="2" name="operation2">
        </Operation>
    </Client>
</Clients>
```

Dataframe:

```
+----+------+----+--------------------+
| _ID| _name|_age|           Operation|
+----+------+----+--------------------+
|   1|teste1|  10|[[1,operation1], ...|
|null|  null|null|                null|
+----+------+----+--------------------+
```

Code:

```
Dataset<Row> clients = sparkSession.sqlContext().read()
                  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
                  .option("rowTag", "Client")
                  .schema(getSchemaClient())
                  .load(dirtorio);

        clients.show(10);

public StructType getSchemaClient() {
        return new StructType(
                new StructField[] { 
                        new StructField("_ID", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                        new StructField("_name", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                        new StructField("_age", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                        new StructField("Operation", DataTypes.createArrayType(this.getSchemaOperation()), true, Metadata.empty()) });
    }

    public StructType getSchemaOperation() {
        return new StructType(new StructField[] {
                new StructField("_ID", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                new StructField("_name", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Version 0.5.0 was just released, which resolved issues with self-closing tags. It may resolve this issue. See https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/pull/352